# # How to suspend and logout of tty?

Tags: suspend, tty

When I want to lock my computer for a long time, I usually exit the GUI and
logout of the tty because Linux screenlockers often aren't very secure.
However, I want to suspend the computer after I have logged out. How can I do
this?

What I have tried:
`systemctl suspend &;exit` // This only suspended, did not exit.
`exit &;systemctl suspend` // This exited, did not suspend.

I have also tried `vlock` instead of `exit`, but there was no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main suggestion:**

Use `exec` to have the shell immediately replace itself.

- To suspend and log out:

  ```
  $ exec systemctl suspend
  ```
- Or, to start GUI and log out:

  ```
  $ exec startx
  ```

**Explanations:**

`&;` is not valid in the shell because both `;` *and* `&` are command separators on their own (and you cannot chain multiple command separators, e.g. `a ; ; b` would not be valid either).

(In other words, `&` isn't its own type of "background" operator – it's just a version of `;` that also puts the command in background.)

The correct way – syntactically, at least – would be to use `&` alone:

```
$ systemctl suspend & exit
```

Usually this won't work, though for a different reason – the shell may refuse to exit when a `&` background job is still running, to avoid accidentally killing the job (or losing the job into the void). If you *do* want to lose the background job into the void and let it do its thing, you can either `disown` the job, or use tricks to avoid it being tracked by the shell at all:

- `disown` to make the shell no longer track it:

  ```
  $ systemctl suspend & disown ; exit
  ```
- Subshell to bypass job tracking entirely:

  ```
  $ (systemctl suspend &) ; exit
  ```

A plain `;` should also work – since "systemctl" suspends the system, "exit" will technically happen only after the system is resumed, but it will happen regardless. Though this is not 100% robust, especially if you distrust X11 screen lockers; there's a *tiny* risk of someone Ctrl+C'ing the command immediately after resuming.

```
$ systemctl suspend; exit
```

A more reliable method is the `exec` keyword which *replaces* the shell with the command that will be run. Once that command exits, it will no longer return to the shell (which is not there anymore) but will effectively log you out, if you exec'd it from your login shell.

```
$ exec systemctl suspend
```

However, it would be simpler to apply this to your GUI so that logging out wouldn't even return you to the tty in the first place:

```
$ exec startx
```

Comment: exec systemctl suspend worked, thank you

Comment: Do you know why ```systemctl suspend &;exit``` doesn't work? It seems weird to me.

Comment: Does it say "Unexpected token" or does it fail in some other way?

Comment: It suspends, but when I turn it back on, it isn't locked. I think it might be because ```exit``` gets executed before ```systemctl suspend```. And when the shell is gone, ```systemctl suspend``` also terminates.